# Glove box on Kia Forte 2010 won't open. What are my options for opening it?

Tags: repair, kia, forte

The glove compartment has a flimsy plastic latch to open and close. Mine hasn't worked in over a year. It was not working well for a while and eventually it just stopped working all together. When I lift the latch I can tell that nothing is happening in terms of whatever it normally does to get the glove box open.

I'm wondering how can I open it? To replace it I need to open it first, I believe. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest a crow bar, but I don't think that's what you're after. More than likely you'll need to look up from the bottom to see where the latch is supposed to be working from and see if you can pull whatever mechanism avails itself from that side. Not really sure as this is pretty subjective depending on what exactly is broke, which isn't presenting itself from your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into an what sounds like an identical problem a couple years ago on my 2002 Saturn VUE. The wire connecting the external plastic latch to the internal catch holding the glove box closed had snapped at the latch.

In my case, I was able to use a screwdriver to pry the external latch assembly partially off the front of the glove box and access the broken wire, then using a pair of needle-nose pliers, pull the wire far enough to release the internal catch mechanism.

Another possible solution might be if you can pry one side of the glove box far enough to reach the internal catch with some small, thin tool and release it that way.

Either way, your glove box likely won't close afterwards, and your options are to either replace the external latch assembly, or buy a new glove box.

Comment: Yup. It's the wire that stopped working. Thanks for the help. I'll start looking at replacement glove boxes.